# I cannot access tor on my network? my network is secured by Cyberoam. Any help?

Tags: censorship

My college network is secured by Cyberoam. I downloaded TOR but I m not able to set it up . Actually I  don't know what the problem is but I think that Cyberoam has blocked the TOR application. Please help me resolve this problem. Every help is welcome

Answer (score 0):

OK, here is what you should do:

- **First**, pre-seed it from a working connection. Anywhere. Just run it and let it be up for a ten minutes
- **Second**, take a close look at pluggable transport, especially on Obfs3, Obfs4 and Meek
- **Third**, take a look at bridges.
- **Four**, take a look at `UseEntryGuards 0` setting, it may help you **after** reseeding. It is the "last resort" option **if no other thing helps/works**

Feel free to ask further questions!

Comment: Why `UseEntryGuards 0`? It reduces security.

Comment: Yes, but if pre-seeded, in a censored-by-IP case it helps. Sadly guards IP's are enumerable....

Comment: Using bridges handles that case without doing anything improper, though.

Comment: unless the fact that  bridges that do publish their descriptors are blacklited on such firewalls too

Comment: Bridges do not publish their descriptors to the consensus, they publish their descriptors to the BridgeDB if they publish them at all. BridgeDB is far less enumerable than the consensus, which is where they'd be getting any other relays ORPort from. The adversary has access to the same list as the user. Not using EntryGuards is *both* *harmful to anonymity* and *achieves less* than using Bridges.

Comment: A script that threshes bridges in some place s a done-task for me. It IS simple : just keep querying and list them. It **does** backfires, sadly...

Comment: First of all, no, it's not simple, say you run your script and you're randomly enumerating the results returned from bridgedb, how do you know when you have all the nodes? You also need to run this enumerating script forever to keep up with any new nodes that are added and you've no meaningful guarantees that you will ever get a full list. Whereas they will always have a guaranteed full list of relays from the consensus. Suggesting people disable entry guards for this reason is **purely harmful** and your justification of it is flimsy and ill-conceived. Please stop recommending this to users.

Comment: @canonizingironize First of all, I'm speaking about *as an option*, not as a must-do-solution. It is not good for anonymity - YES, but it's much better than nothing, and in an IP-blacklists case it *is helping* sometimes, when nothing else works at all. And this script is being set on `cron` can do a big harm to Tor anonymity - there are a lot of caveats, but it is a very powerful tool. That's why I'm not publishing it anywhere - to make sure that it will never be in the wrong hands. And - I hope you won't argue that Tor working with it set is worse than tor not working at all

Comment: It is **always** a **much worse** option than bridges, Tor appearing to work but in reality providing little to no protection for the user is indeed worse than tor not working. If straight bridges, obfs{3,4}, or meek do not work then you need to find a better method to bypass the censor, removing guards is **never** the right solution.

Comment: @canonizingironize I do agree, that this option is worse than using a bridge - correct, but I strongly disagree with the "need to find a better method to bypass the censor" part - it provides no solution. And - yes - even using guards you can encounter a bad node, see [prooflink](https://threatpost.com/researcher-finds-tor-exit-node-adding-malware-to-binaries/109008/). So - I think that it is bad, **but working** solution **if nothing else works**. I can explain why in details, if you do need the explanation

Comment: Your "prooflink" is totally unrelated to the problem being discussed. First of all, your solution might work briefly but the censor would quickly catch on then it would be trivial to block. It's harmful and it's a short term solution to a long term problem, and yes leaving users vulnerable to targeted deanonymization attacks rather than trying to find a better solution, like tunneling tor over some other connection medium is definitely worse. If you cannot see the problems with not even warning users they'd be vulnerable when you recommend this, then you're a danger to users and a liability.

Comment: @canonizingironize if bridges does not work, then it can be a last resort... And the prooflink proves that even using entry guards you *can potentially* occur a malicious node. Entry guards are just stable nodes, but not all of them, no special extra checks: for example my node has received a Guard flag but **nobody** has audited it. And a risk using Guards is the same as using another nodes with reachable ORPort.

Comment: The problem is not that guards are extra trustworthy, the problem is that an adversary who controls the guard and the exit can deanonymize a user. If you disable entryguards you will always pick a random entry node, not keep them long term, as such you will be far more likely to pick the "bad" guard and exit pair, and the attacker could do better still to properly deanonymize the user, left as an excercise to the reader to figure out how. https://blog.torproject.org/blog/improving-tors-anonymity-changing-guard-parameters

Comment: @canonizingironize If you disable entryguards you will be picking randomly from *all* the nodes, *including* guards. Yes, it **is** decreasing entry-exit node selection safety, 101% agreed! **But it is still better rather than coming through 100%-sure invading/censoring proxy/firewall**. In case of disabling entryguargs I see it as a "last resort" case, the **very last thing you're about to try**: it's not a quest for the best solution in that case, it is a picking the lesser evil.

Comment: You recommended bridges as the last thing to try. I think you do not understand the risks to the user. Given the choice of not using Tor or being tortured and/or killed, many people might like to know that disabling entry guards to access Tor increases the risks of the first one happening such that a determined adversary *will* find out who they are over a long enough time period. If you recommend this you should certainly be pointing out the risks, it is reckless and irresponsible not to. You do not know the risks or situation, let them judge for themselves by informing them. EOF.

Comment: @canonizingironize Point taken, changed an order of enumeration